# pandas series multiindex extracting first 3 rows

Tags: pandas, series

My data looks like the following. It is a Series with two levels of index. It came from `groupby` operation and sorting.

```
CUISINE DESCRIPTION  CAMIS   
American             40916695    88
                     41709379    70
                     41706342    69
                     50000543    69
                     41164678    68
Asian                40402428    167
                     41459743    95
                     41533453    94       
                     50001962    63 
...
```

How do I get the first 3 rows of every cuisine? i.e.,

```
American             40916695    88
                     41709379    70
                     41706342    69
Asian                40402428    167
                     41459743    95
                     41533453    94
...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perform a `groupby` on `level=0`, and then take `head(3)`:

```
df.groupby(level=0).head(3)
```

Since your index is named, you can also do `level='CUISINE'`, if you feel that it's more readable.